# How to locate elements for validator.ampproject.org to automate amp validation using Selenium and Java/JS?

Tags: java, html, selenium, polymer, amp-html

[image]

This type of tags are present in the UI. I want to automate to put URL in required field in UI and validate the status.

Answer (score 1):

I see a input that has an id `input`:

did you try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id('input')).sendKeys('your url to be sent here');
```

Comment: Hi cruisepandey , I tried this method . Stale element exception is throwing for it

Comment: @Shubham  : Is page URL available  ?

Comment: page url is visible in screenshot and question itself

Comment: Posting an image is not encouraged here, we don't entertain such thing here. Try to post in text format.

Comment: try accessing the element as `this.$.input`